# Find words frequency from a large file

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, lucene, bigdata

I have a text file like this:

```
tom
and
jerry
went
to
america
and
england
```

I want to get the frequency of each word including partial matches too. ie, the word `to` present in the word `tom`. So my expected word count of `to` is 2.

```
   1 america
   3 and
   1 england
   1 jerry
   2 to
   1 tom
   1 went
```

The text file I have is around **30gb** hence its not possible to load all the content in memory. 
So What I am doing right now is:

1. reading the input file using `scanner`
2. for each word finding the frequency using this code:

   `Long wordsCount = Files.lines(Paths.get(allWordsFile))
                   .filter(s->s.contains(word)).count();`

ie, for each word I am looping the entire file content. Even though I am using `threadpool executor`, the performance of this approach is really poor. 
Is there a better way of doing this?
Any tools are available to find the frequency of the words from a **large** file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by partial matches? Does suffix matches count to or only prefix matches?

Comment: @DanielMesejo added the sample in question. the word `to` present in the word `tom`. so we need to consider `tom` also when we search the frequency of `to`

Comment: I see, but `and` is contained in `england` but the count is only two, shouldn't be 3?

Comment: Let's say we have `to`, `tom`, `tomas` what is your expected word count for `to` and `tom`?

Comment: Have you tried loading all the words into RadixTree? With string deduplication, I think it won't consume a massive amount of memory.
e.g, https://github.com/npgall/concurrent-trees/blob/master/documentation/ConcurrentRadixTreeUsage.md?

Comment: [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) might be worth a look: easy to search for all keys matching a prefix.

Comment: @Gelerion to-3, tom-2, tomas-1. i tried radix tree, but it supports prefix match only.

Comment: What are you doing with the `Long`? You get a `Long` for each word (why not `long`), but what then?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are a lot of repetitions you could try something like this (wrote this from scratch may not compile perfectly)

```
File file = 
  new File("fileLoc"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

Map <String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
String name;
while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) 
    if(hm.containsKey(name){
        hm.replace(name,hm.get(name) + 1);
    }
    else{
        hm.put(name,1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I didnt notice the partial matches part but you should be able to just loop back through the map after reading the enter file so that way if theres a partial match just combine the partial match value with the match value

Answer (score 0):

The best in term of performance is to read the lines from the file with a BufferedReader, and to store the word counter in a HashMap.

Comment: It's what you are requesting, ie having for every word the word count... the map is supposed to be smaller than your data if there are duplicated words.
Feel free to implement an "on disk" hashmap if you are short in memory.